# Why the animation on the dropdown menu not working with Tailwind CSS classes

Tags: javascript, html, tailwind-css

I'm trying to implement animation on a dropdown menu using Tailwind CSS. I have a  element with classes that should trigger a transition when the burger button is clicked, but the animation isn't happening as expected.

Here's a snippet of the HTML and JavaScript I'm using:

***HTML:***

```
<nav id="dropdown" class="hidden py-5 px-4 bg-grayshade-10 border-b-[1px] border-grayshade-15 flex gap-5 flex-col items-center text-white text-barlow transition ease-out duration-200">
    <a class="hover:text-greenshade-60 active:text-greenshade-80" href="=">Home</a>
    <a class="hover:text-greenshade-60 active:text-greenshade-80" href="=">Service</a>
    <a class="hover:text-greenshade-60 active:text-greenshade-80" href="=">Work</a>
    <a class="hover:text-greenshade-60 active:text-greenshade-80" href="=">Process</a>
    <a class="hover:text-greenshade-60 active:text-greenshade-80" href="=">About</a>
</nav>
```

***JS***

```
const burger = document.querySelector("#burgermenu");
const burgerLine = document.querySelector("#linecontainer");

const dropMenu = document.querySelector("#dropdown");

burger.addEventListener("click", () => {
  burgerLine.classList.toggle("burgerActive");
  dropMenu.classList.toggle("hidden");
});
```

I'm hoping to enable animation when the dropdown appears or disappears, but the animation isn't happening at all. Is there something wrong with the approach or the classes I'm using in Tailwind CSS? Thank you for any help and insights!

And here's a GIF showing the issue:

[image]

Comment: `hidden` applies `display: none`. There is no transition that can happen when changing the value of `display`.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to transition? Opacity? Vertical position (ie slide-down)? I'd expect to see something like `transition-transform` or `transition-opacity` somewhere. See more: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property